# Twitter API Media entities always empty

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm trying to get a list of tweets from one user and retrieve the media urls from the entities.
When I look at the json feeding the tweet on the twitter website, it has a media object in the entities as documented, but when I use the API the media is missing.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=TWEET_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add &tweet_mode=extended to get the media

Comment: I set it as extended but still empty